# Average time without changing format using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe, python-3.6

Below is my  avg_df:

```
         Date Model  INumber        Type TimeDiff Device
326  20/07/18    TG     I625  Devicetime  0:02:31   RD
328  20/07/18    TG    I5271  Devicetime  0:00:32   RD
332  20/07/18    TG     I660  Devicetime  0:00:31   RD
```

I want to get average of "TimeDiff". I know that i can convert Time into secs and get avg and can format it back, but would be interested to know if there is any way that i can get without formatting time back and forth. something like below:

`print(avg_df.loc[:,"TimeDiff"].mean())`

Appreciate any help!

Comment: That would require there to be a method whereby Timestamp objects could be divided by floats/ints.  I don't think that can be done, so a mean without first transforming to a numerical representation is not possible.

Comment: ok, Is there any other better alternate solution where i can get average of "TimeDiff"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the average if you convert it to `timedelta` first:

```
>>> pd.to_timedelta(df['TimeDiff']).mean()
Timedelta('0 days 00:01:11.333333')
```